# Twython get_retweeters_ids gives 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: python, twitter, twython

I am using Twython to convert some tweet IDs in tweets object. Then I select only those that have been retweeted at least once and I try to obtain the list of retweeters IDs via

```
.get_retweeters_ids (user_id = XXX)
```

but I get

```
Twitter API returned a 400 (Bad Request), Bad request.
```

I have been taking a look around and it looks to me that this error has to do with authentication, but this sounds really strange to me for the following reason:

In my code, first I call

```
.lookup_status()
```

and then I call

```
.get_retweeters_ids (user_id = XXX)
```

and as far as I can understand from the Twython documentation they are both allowed with a user_auth, that is the one I have. So I really don't understand why I can use the `lookup_status()` method but not the `get_retweeters_ids()` one.

Any suggestion appreciated.

Comment: get_retweeters_ids you should not use user_id, but tweet_id

Comment: OH MEN! thank you, that was the issue! ...